# How to model diamond like many-to-many relationship in database ERD

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-design, erd, database-diagram

[image: organization_id as foreign key]
[image: organization_id as primary key]

Legend:

- **PK (Blue):** Primary key
- **FK (Green):** Foreign key
- **PFK (Blue):** Primary Key and Foreign Key at the same time

How to model a diamond like (if term is correct) relationship? Better to explain using a simplified example:

There is `organization`, `item` and `tag` entities.

My aim is to model:

1. Every `tag` is unique by itself and belongs to a single organization.
2. Every `item` is unique by itself and belongs to a single organization.
3. Items have many tags (joined using M2M table) and related `tag`/`item` pairs must belong to same organization. (i.e. item from organization A cannot pair with a tag from organization B)

I diagrammed two alternative solutions, but none of them satisfied me.

**Diagram 1 breaks 3rd aim**: `items` and `tags` are unique by themselves using `id` as primary key, but there is nothing to stop insert pairs into `item_tag` which belong to different organization.

**Diagram 2 does not break, but bends 1st and 2nd aims**: `organization_id` is added as a Primary and Foreign Key to `item` and `tag` tables and `item_tag.organization_id` column references both. This prevents pairs from different organization. `tag.id` and `item.id` columns are part of a unnecessary composite primary key now, because in reality single `id` column represents uniqueness of the `item` and `tag`.

How can I model those requirements correctly?

Comment: `FOREIGN KEYs` have limitations.  You are possibly hitting their limits, in which case, you need to write application code to enforce the constraints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To enforce referential integrity, you'll have to ...

- include `organization_id` in all tables
- create logically redundant `UNIQUE` (or PK) constraints on `(organization_id, id)`    in both tables `tag` and `item`
- have multicolumn FK constraints in `item_tag` matching the columns of those `UNIQUE`  constraints.

If you don't include the `organization_id` (logically redundantly) there would be nothing to keep you from linking items and tags from different organizations (by mistake).

That would be your **diagram 2**. But do you really need data type `uuid` for tags? `bigint` or even `int` should suffice, while being a bit smaller and faster.

Closely related case with code example for PostgreSQL:

- [Enforcing constraints “two tables away”](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58970/enforcing-constraints-two-tables-away/58972#58972)

Comment: Brandsletter, thanks for the answer. uuid is used here for example purposes.  Proposed solution is exactly same as diagram 2 (`PFK`: Primary + foreign key), but I want to avoid filling unnecessary columns to `UNIQUE` or `PK`.

Comment: @ozm: It is indeed. I tried the same before and did not find a better way without redundant `UNIQUE` constraint as demonstrated in the linked answer.